# Publishing with Visual Studio how do I control how image resources get deployed.?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, resources

I have 223 image resources in my resource.resx.   When publishing with Visual Studio, most of my image resources get included as .png.deploy files in a "resources" folder.  But many others get included without a .png.deploy file. What is the difference between these two behaviors and how do I control it?

in the Resources.Designer file, these two behaviors seem identical:

```
      '''<summary>
      '''  Looks up a localized resource of type System.Drawing.Bitmap.
      '''</summary>
      Friend ReadOnly Property masYellowYellow() As System.Drawing.Bitmap
          Get
              Dim obj As Object = ResourceManager.GetObject("masYellowYellow", resourceCulture)
              Return CType(obj,System.Drawing.Bitmap)
          End Get
      End Property
      
      '''<summary>
      '''  Looks up a localized resource of type System.Drawing.Bitmap.
      '''</summary>
      Friend ReadOnly Property r2() As System.Drawing.Bitmap
          Get
              Dim obj As Object = ResourceManager.GetObject("r2", resourceCulture)
              Return CType(obj,System.Drawing.Bitmap)
          End Get
      End Property
```

yet, **r2** gets deployed as a **r2.png.deploy** file in the resources folder and **masYellowYellow** get deployed "virtually?"

Comment: The whole point of resources is that they are compiled into the assembly (EXE or DLL) rather than loose files. If you really have resources then there is no separate file to deploy so, if you have separate files, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: But what am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: I would start by adding a new resource and publishing again to see whether it behaves properly, i.e. the file is not included separately in the publish. That will indicate whether the IDE is doing something wrong now or it was either you or the IDE that did something wrong in the past. Once we know that, we can determine what the next step should be.

Comment: I found the difference between the two behaviors.  Looking at each resource-file's properties (in the solution explorer) the ones behaving correctly had BUILD ACTION set to "none".  The one's causing the extra files in the publish deployment had BUILD ACTION set to "content".

Any idea on how these automatically get set differently?

Comment: Also take a look at the document - [Build actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?view=vs-2019)